# Accounting for spatial autocorrelation and grouping random effect in nlme

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation

I would like to test differences in mean values of a **Climate_variable** between 4 different climatic **Scenarios** that are projected for many (3000) surveyed **Sites** for which I know the coordinates (**Lon** and **Lat**). My database is structured as follows:

| Climate_variable | Scenario | Site | Lon | Lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.85 | A | S1 | 19.37 | 41.85 |
| 1.13 | B | S1 | 19.37 | 41.85 |
| 1.55 | C | S1 | 19.37 | 41.85 |
| 2.12 | D | S1 | 19.37 | 41.85 |
| 0.74 | A | S2 | 21.42 | 40.36 |
| 1.08 | B | S2 | 21.42 | 40.36 |
| 1.44 | C | S2 | 21.42 | 40.36 |
| 2.01 | D | S2 | 21.42 | 40.36 |

Because I have 4 observations for each **Site** but I am not interested in this effect, I wanted to go for a Linear Mixed Model with **Site** as random effect. However, climatic variables are often highly spatially autocorrelated so I also wanted to add a spatial autocorrelation structure using the coordinates of the sites.

This is the code I run using the *nlme* package on R:

```
mod <- lme(Climate_variable ~ Scenario,
           correlation = corExp(form = ~Lon+Lat),
           random = list(~1|Site))
```

However, there is an error message saying *cannot have zero distances in "corSpatial"*, I guess because I have 4 observation with the same coordinates for each site.

So I tried this instead:

```
mod <- lme(Climate_variable ~ Scenario,
           correlation = corExp(form = ~Lon+Lat | Scenario),
           random = list(~1|Site))
```

But I get another error message: *incompatible formulas for groups in 'random' and 'correlation'*

How could I account for both the spatial autocorrelation and the non-independance of the observations for different **Scenarios** on the same **Site**?

Comment: It looks like Site is completely determined by Lon and Lat. If so, then it doesn't make sense to include both Lat/Lon as well as Site in the model - this is including redundant information. I would remove Site and just retain Lon and Lat.

Comment: @mkt Indeed, I finaly opted for another model specification without redundancy!

Answer (score 1):

I have to tell you that i do it different. First i make the null model indicating  fixed and random. If you put site as random, you are telling the program to control for the different between sites, that i think is not what you want. right?  You want to control for the difference between the scenarios. Then scenario is random.
example from the package.

```
null.model <- lme(fixed = thick ~ 1, data = spdata, random = ~ 1 | dummy)

exp.sp <- update(null.model, correlation = corExp(1, form = ~ east + north), method = "ML")
```

Your error."There is an error message saying cannot have zero distances in "corSpatial", I guess because I have 4 observation with the same coordinates for each site."
Exactly is because you have the same coordinates and when the program try to calculate the geographic distance to check for autocorrelation give 0, that for the program sound absurd.   I think this method is not the correct if you only have one site. This is for checking spatial autocorrelation. It is better you only check for correlation in your scenarios in a simple way.

Comment: No I am actually interrested in the Scenario effect and not in the Site effect, so I want to control for differences between sites.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this analysis might not be relevant (see comment from @mkt), this code works:

`mod <- lme(Climate_variable ~ Scenario, correlation = corExp(form = ~(Lon+Lat)/Scenario), random = list(~1|Site))`

Comment: I have the same question as yours. Your code could be a solution. But do you know what the slash before Scenario means in the wording of this formula, as opposed to the vertical bar in the former script?

Comment: The main question remains: is this model really inadequate as @mkt suggests? One can have a random effect of the Site, which one wants to be able to estimate, and at the same time, in the same model, a correlation structure of the residuals (which will necessarily be different for each Scenario), more precise than a simple random effect. But I am not sure. If someone can confirm or deny, thank you in advance.